# Recycling a Button for individual object - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I am a beginner in Unity and I am currently making a simple game. I have a problem where the button should reappear on the object I am getting contact with. It only shows on the first object that I put the script on.

What I wanted to do is to have a recyclable button that will appear whenever I have contact with objects like the "view" button in most of the games. What keeps happening in my project is that the collision is triggered but the position of the object is in the first object where I put the script to set it active and set the position. I put it in another object because I want the button to show in that object but it keeps appearing in the first object.

This is the script I used:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractNPC : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public Button UI;
    [SerializeField] GameObject uiUse, nameBtn, dialogBox;
    [SerializeField] TextAsset characterData;
    // [SerializeField] UnityEngine.UI.Text dialogMessage;
    private Transform head;
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 1.0f, 0);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //uiUse = Instantiate(UI, FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform).GetComponent<Button>();
        uiUse.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        head = this.transform.GetChild(0);
        uiUse.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);
        nameBtn.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);

        nameBtn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(onNameClick);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        uiUse.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);
        nameBtn.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            //Character characterJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<Character>(characterData.text);

            nameBtn.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            // Text lbl = nameBtn.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren(typeof(Text), true) as Text;
            // lbl.text = "BOBO";
            // nameBtn.GetComponent<Button>().GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = characterJson.name;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            nameBtn.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // DIALOGUE SYSTEM
    public void onNameClick()
    {
        Text dialogMessage, dialogName;
        if (dialogBox.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {  
            dialogName = GameObject.Find("Canvas/DialogBox/DialogueName").GetComponent<Text>();
            dialogMessage = GameObject.Find("Canvas/DialogBox/Dialogue").GetComponent<Text>();
            if (dialogMessage != null && dialogName != null)
            {
                loadCharacterData(dialogMessage, dialogName);
                Debug.Log("not null dialog message");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("null dialog message");
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadCharacterData(Text dialogMessage, Text dialogName)
    {
        Character characterJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<Character>(characterData.text);
        dialogName.text = characterJson.name;

        dialogMessage.text = characterJson.dialogs[0].choices[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure ... you mean you want to re-use the very same button instance in your scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your issue is that each and every instnce of your scrip will all the time overwrite

```
void Update()
{
    uiUse.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);
    nameBtn.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);
}
```

**every frame**.

What you want is set it only **once** in

```
[SerializeField] private Button nameBtn;

pivate Character character;

private void Start()
{
    ...

    // do this only once!
    character = JsonUtility.FromJson<Character>(characterData.text);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        nameBtn.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        var lbl = nameBtn.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);
        lbl.text = characterJson.name;

        var position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);

        uiUse.transform.position = position;
        nameBtn.transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

---

Further you will have another issue: Each and every instance of your script attaches a callback

```
nameBtn.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(onNameClick);
```

that is not good! Now whenever you click the button once, the allback is fired for each and every instance of your script.

You would rather do this only if the click was actually invoked for the current object.

For this you could attach the listener only add-hoc when needed like e.g.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        ...

        nameBtn.onClick.RemoveListener(onNameClick);
        nameBtn.onClick.AddListener(onNameClick);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (collisionInfo.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        nameBtn.onClick.RemoveListener(onNameClick);

        nameBtn.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

---

ok we didn't know before your objects move

so well you will need to go back to what you had before and update the position continuously, **BUT** only while you are the current active object so e.g.

```
private static InteractNPC buttonOwner;
private Camera mainCamera;

void Update()
{
    if(buttonOwner != this) return;

    if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
    var position = mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(head.position + offset);

    uiUse.transform.position = position;
    nameBtn.transform.position = position;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.CompareTag("Player") && !buttonOwner)
    {
        ...

        buttonOwner = this;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (collisionInfo.CompareTag("Player") && buttonOwner == this)
    {
        nameBtn.onClick.RemoveListener(onNameClick);

        nameBtn.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        buttonOwner = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But when I move around the NPC the button move along with the screen because it just spawns and there is no keeping it in place (on the top of the head of the NPC). How do I keep it in place when I move around the NPC?

Comment: @RichardJohnson see update at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! last question. the statement `lbl.text = characterJson.name;` returns an error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I tried to output the `characterJson.name` in `Debug.Log()`, but it is not null and displays the name. What could be the problem?

Comment: What does the if statement `if(buttonOwner != this) return;` check? Just needed to understand it more. thanks

Comment: @RichardJohnson you check if `this` instance of `InteractNPC` is currently the one that "owns" the button => it was the one triggering it, listening to onClick and updating its position. Other instances of your script that are not the owner shouldn't do this

Comment: @RichardJohnson and if `characterJson.name` is prints correctly it can only mean that `lbl` is `null`

Comment: I solved the problem of lbl being null by creating a public instance and referencing the text in the Unity. And thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see you never create a new Button, I guess that Unity may think, you want the same Button on all NPCs.

Maybe try to call the constructor for a new Button in the Start Method and see if it then generates a new Button per NPC.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, recycle a button on every NPC. The same button will appear everytime I come in contact with new NPC, the only thing that will change is that individual NPC information like name which I will handle through JSON. I don't know what to do to achieve this kind of thing.