# How to assign multiple functions to a button at different times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a button to do multiple things but not at the same time.

For e.g. in the game, when the player comes near the door and press the button, i want it to open the door. And when player comes near a weapon and press the SAME button, i want the player to pick up the weapon.

P.S. I'm making a game for mobile.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could for example use an **enum** and set a value/type on it.
You can set a value when you are near a door, for example, and overwrite it when you are near a weapon.

As soon as the button is pressed, you simply check the value of the enum and execute an action based on the value.

```
enum Actions
{
    OpenDoor,
    NearWeapon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need different callbacks for this.

I would have one single callback react differently to whatever you are close to.

This is pretty much the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863765/recycling-a-button-for-individual-object-unity3d/73863921#73863921). Slightly different use case but the principle is similar.

There is basically two main option

- Either the target objects implement the logic => use a common interface/base class
- Your player implements the logic => use whatever to differ between the object types

Then your player could check what it "is close to" - I will just assume physics again but how exactly you check what you are "close to" is up to you - and interact with that target object.

---

#### Interface

You could simply have a shared interface like e.g.

```
public interface IInteractable
{
    void Interact(/*pass in whatever arguments you need e.g.*/Player player);
}
```

and then have your classes implement it and the logic e.g.

```
public class Door : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    public void Interact(Player player)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    public void Interact(Player player)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

and then assuming you use physics (triggers) you could do e.g.

```
public class Player : Monobehaviour
{
    [SerialzieField] private Button button;

    // we will store multiple close objects so we can smoothly transition between them in case 
    // we are close to multiple ones - up to you of course
    private readonly List<IInteractable> currentActives = new();

    private void Awake()
    {
        i(!button) button = GetComponent<Buton>();

        // you attach a snigle callback
        button.onClick.AddListener(Interact);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEner(Collider other)
    {
        // does this object have an IInteractable 
        var interactable = other.GetComponentInParent<IInteractable>();

        if(interactable == null) return;

        currentCloses.Add(interactable);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        // was the object an IInteractable?
        var interactable = other.GetComponentInParent<IInteractable>(true);

        if(interactable == null) return;

        currentCloses.Remove(interactable);
    }

    private void Interact()
    {
        // some Linq magic to pick the closest item - again up to you
        var currentClosest = currentCloses.Select(item => (MonoBehaviour)item).OrderBy(item => (item.transform.position, transform.position).sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();

        if(currentClosest == null) return;

        // now let that object handle the interaction
        // this class doesn't need to know what exactly this means at all
        currentClosest.Interact(this);
    }
}
```

This is of course a little bit inflexible and you always need to have a common shared interface and pass along all needed parameters. It can also get quite dirty if e.g. the weapon implements its own "pick up" - doesn't feel quite right.

---

#### Different Types

You could simply have different types (components) on your target objects, lets say e.g.

```
// have a common shared base class
public abstract class Interactable : MonoBeaviour
{
}
```

and then have derived types

```
public class Door : Interactable
{
    // they can either implement their own logic
    public void Open()
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

and e.g.

```
public class Weapon : Interactable
{
    // this one is purely used to differ between the type
    // we rather expect whoever uses this will implement the logic instead
}
```

and then pretty similar as above

```
public class InteractionController : Monobehaviour
{
    [SerialzieField] private Button button;

    private readonly List<Interactable> currentActive = new();

    private void Awake()
    {
        i(!button) button = GetComponent<Buton>();

        button.onClick.AddListener(Interact);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEner(Collider other)
    {
        var interactable = other.GetComponentInParent<Interactable>();

        if(!interactable) return;

        currentCloses.Add(interactable);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        var interactable = other.GetComponentInParent<Interactable>();

        if(!interactable) return;

        currentCloses.Remove(interactable);
    }

    private void Interact()
    {
        var currentClosest = currentCloses.OrderBy(item => (item.transform.position, transform.position).sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();

        if(currentClosest == null) return;
        
        // just that this one you check which actual type this component has
        // and deal with it accordingly, completely customizable
        switch(currentActive)
        {
            case Door door: 
                door.Open();
                break;

            case Weapon weapon:
                PickupWeapon(weapon);
                break;

            default:
                Debug.LogError($"Interaction with {currentActive.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName} is not implemented!");
                break;
        }
    }

    // Just as example that the target doesn't even need to implement the method itself
    private void PickupWeapon(Weapon weapon)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```